# Material-dependent transparency in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, mesh, cturtle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

By request I'm reposting this question from the ros-users mailing list. Again, my apologies if this issue has been addressed elsewhere previously, but I was unable to find an answer after searching around for a while.

My problem is that whenever I spawn a gazebo object with certain basic material properties (e.g. Blue, Gold), it is transparent when viewed in front of the ground plane. If I adjust the camera to look at it horizontally, I can then see the top part of the object that projected onto the sky.

However, if I spawn the same object, but change its material to, e.g. RustySteel, it is completely visible. For example, if I spawn the table object using the table.launch script in gazebo_worlds, I can see the table top (LightWood) but not the legs (Red). There are no error messages in the console.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I'm sure there's a relatively straightforward solution, but it has alluded me so far :)

System info:
Ubuntu Maverick (2.6.35-25) 64bit running on Parallels VM on MBP i7
ROS C Turtle, all packages are up to date.

I was also able to reproduce this problem on a Dell Quad Core running 64bit Maverick.

Thanks in advance!

```
--sk
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9237/material-dependent-transparency-in-gazebo/) by [scottk](https://answers.ros.org/users/211/scottk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo's sensor simulation which relies on Ogre libraries have been known to be problematic on VM's.  What types of (emulated) GPU and GPU driver are you using?

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lalith](https://answers.ros.org/users/4628/lalith/) on 2013-04-07**:
hi, i am also facing the same issue, may i know how to solve it?